# My Action doesn't redirect me to the index view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello as I'm so new to Mvc I woild appreciate any Help!

So Here is myModels

**Category**

-CategoryID

-DateCreated

**CategoriesLanguages**

ID (autoincrement)

CategoryID

LanguageID

Title

Description

Basically when I click Add button in my Index() View - I'm redirected to AddCategory() Action which just add  a new record in Categories Table and returns me a view with text boxes and button in which the user can populate the data for CategoriesLanguages table
When i click the button I make an ajax request to AddCategoriesLanguages()action and everything is fine - it adds the record in the database but at the end when i say RedirectToAction("Index") nothing happens.

here is my CategorViewModel.cs

```
 public class CategoryViewModel
        {

            public List<Language> lstLanguages { get; set; }
            public List<CategoryLanguages> lstCategoryLanguages { get; set; }
            public CategoryLanguages categoryToEdit { get; set; }
            private readonly ICategoryRepository catRep;
            private readonly ILanguageRepository lanRep;
            private readonly ICategoryLanguageRepository catlanRep;


            public CategoryViewModel()
                : this(new CategoryRepository(),new LanguageRepository(),new CategoryLanguageRepository() )
            {

            }

            public CategoryViewModel(ICategoryRepository catRep, ILanguageRepository lanRep, ICategoryLanguageRepository catlanRep)
            {
                this.catRep = catRep;
                this.lanRep = lanRep;
                this.catlanRep = catlanRep;
            }


            public void AddNewCategory()
            {
                lstLanguages = lanRep.GetAllAvailableLanguages();
                newCategoryID = catRep.AddCategory();

            }

            public void AddCategoriesLanguages(int catID, int lanID, string title, string shortDescription, string description)
            {
                catlanRep.AddCategoryLanguage(catID, lanID, title, shortDescription, description);

            }
```

Here is my CategoryController

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CategoryViewModel ob = new CategoryViewModel();
            ob.LoadLanguages();
            return View(ob);
        }



        public ActionResult AddCategory()
        {
            CategoryViewModel vm = new CategoryViewModel();
            vm.AddNewCategory();
            return View(vm);
        }

        public ActionResult AddCategoriesLanguages(int catID, int lanID, string title, string shrtDescription, string description)
        {
            CategoryViewModel vm = new CategoryViewModel();
            vm.AddCategoriesLanguages(catID, lanID, title, shrtDescription, description);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

---

Here is my  View AddCategory.cshtml

```
@model Onion.Web.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel



<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            var variab = 2;

            $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("AddCategoriesLanguages")' + '?catID=' +@Model.newCategoryID +'&lanID=' + $("#ddlLanguages").val() + '&title=' + $('#txbTitle').val() + '&shrtDescription=' + $('#txbShortDescription').val() + '&Description=' + $('#txbDescription').val(),
                data: {}




            });
        });
    });
    </script>

<h2>AddCategory</h2>
@Html.DropDownList("Languages", new SelectList(Model.lstLanguages, "LanguageID", "Name",@HttpContext.Current.Session["langID"]),new { id = "ddlLanguages" })
<br />
<label for="txbTitle">Title:</label>
<input type="text"  id="txbTitle"/>
 <br />
<label for="txbShortDescription">Short Description:</label>
<input type="text"  id="txbShortDescription" />
 <br />
<label for="txbDescription">Description:</label>
<input type="text"  id="txbDescription" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" />
```

Comment: you can try reload the page on ajax.call sucess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this in your view

```
    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("AddCategoriesLanguages")' + '?catID=' +@Model.newCategoryID +'&lanID=' + $("#ddlLanguages").val() + '&title=' + $('#txbTitle').val() + '&shrtDescription=' + $('#txbShortDescription').val() + '&Description=' + $('#txbDescription').val(),
        data: {},
success: function() 
{ 
      var redirect='YOUR URL'; 
       Window.location=redirect;   // dont do anything. --problem.
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an AJAX call to the `AddCategoriesLanguages` action. Returning HTTP 301 from that action won't reload the page in the browser as it's an AJAX call.

You could return Json from `AddCategoriesLanguages` action with the url and in the success callback in your $.ajax call do

> windows.location = result.url;

`RedirectToAction` works only if you're doing a full page POST. You might replace Ajax call with form post, but it's obviously a big impact on your app's client-side architecture.